# Google Maps documentation uses deprecated PHP - how can I update it?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, mysqli, pdo

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

Features deprecated PHP for connecting to a MySQL database, i.e. using mysql instead of mysqli or pdo.

I tried following the tutorial to display markers with set names/lat/lng from a mySQL database, but found that the PHP was deprecated and simply replacing 'mysql' with 'mysqli' gave me a nearly empty XML document.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "pins_db";
$database = "root-pins_db";

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $dbname);

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM pins_table WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($query);

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . $row['name'] . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

The resulting XML document only contains:

```
<markers/>
```

I'm running PHP 7.0.15 and MySQL 5.6.35 on MAMP.

The database info:

```
user/pw: root/root
database: pins_db
table: pins_table
```

The table:

```
1   id  int(11)

2   datetime    datetime

3   lat float(10,6)

4   lng float(10,6)

5   name    text
```

Am I missing something here? I'm fairly new to PHP and very new to mySQL; I can't find an answer to this anywhere else online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on php error reporting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

---

Test for successful execution of the query execution.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if(!$result) {
   // error returned
   die('error#002: '.mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

Remove the `@` (at sign) before the function call, because we do not want to silence php errors:

```
 while ( $row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
                ^
```

---

Also check for a successful connection

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
if(!$connection) {
    die('error connecting: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

It's also possible that `mysqli_select_db` isn't working. For example if the database name is incorrect or doesn't exist.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Note that a database name could be supplied as a fourth argument on `mysqli_connect`.

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thanks ever so much! After turning error reporting on I found that mysqli_query required the connection as a parameter. After entering $connection, I was presented with a generated XML file with all the pins. Hopefully importing these will work with the code given by Google.

Fixed code for future reference:

`$result = mysqli_query($query);` should be `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);`

Comment: @Anthony: I didn't notice the missing `$connection` parameter... I was focused on checking for an error, and notification. (Please note, I'm not recommending that `die` is the most appropriate way to handle errors. That's just a placeholder, to hold us over until we get around to implementing a call to a logging function, and displaying a more friendly page to the end user.. "We apologize for the inconvenience, but something has gone horribly wrong".)

Comment: The `$connection` parameter is required in the call to `mysqli_error`, as well as `mysqli_query`.  Code in answer corrected.